# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start') on Docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have a React app which works perfectly fine locally. However, when I dockerize it and try to run it in a container, I get the following error:

[image]

For reference, this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "graphDemo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "d3": "^5.16.0",
    "pixi-viewport": "^4.21.1",
    "pixi.js": "^5.3.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and my Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:16.16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I'm confused why it won't work in my Docker container. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `currentRenderer`? It's showing it as `undefined` without more insight cannot comment. PS: `COPY package*.json .` so it will copy package-lock.json also.

Comment: I'm using Pixi library so I'm guessing its something to do with how it renders. those errors are not from the code I've written, its probably from the library!